# Installing DRBD in ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, replication, drbd

I have installed drbd8-utils, and edited the drbd.conf file in /etc. But when I try to start drbd I get the following error message.

> root@drbd1:~# service drbd start
>   /etc/drbd.conf:4: Failed to open include file 'drbd.d/*.res'.
>    * Starting DRBD resources                                                      /etc/drbd.conf:4: Failed to open include file 'drbd.d/*.res'.
>   DRBD module version: 8.3.8
>      userland version: 8.3.7
>   you should upgrade your drbd tools!
>   /etc/drbd.conf:4: Failed to open include file 'drbd.d/*.res'.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DRBD is looking for a resource file with a .res extension in /etc/drbd.d and you don't have one.  Evidently you configured the global file but not one for your resources.

Here is the documentation on configuring a resource file. You can almost copy/paste the sample one but you really should read and understand the doc first.

http://www.drbd.org/users-guide-emb/s-configure-resource.html